# Alternatives to ActiveSheet.Paste to reduce memory

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to utilise the VBA/macro function at work. However, I came across a problem which says something like 'error; insufficient memory' and after some browsing on the internet I realise that copy and pasting generally takes up a lot of spaces in the Excel and my Excel in workplace is only 32 bits. Therefore, does anyone know any good alternatives to ActiveSheet.Paste?

My codes are currently as following:

```
ActiveSheet.Range ("$A$!:$Y$1000").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criterial:=_banker
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(x1Down)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(X1ToRight)).Select

Selection.Copy
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Paste

ActiveSheet.Name= banker

i=i+1

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: You are missing the start of your loop, which would probably include your exit condition... It might be running in an infinite loop without an exit condition.

Comment: Add `Option Explicit` to the top of your module and you will see multiple issues with your code as posted.   `Range ("$A$!:$Y$1000")`,  `Selection.End(x1Down)` and `Selection.End(X1ToRight)` all have problems.   Plus you have both  `_banker` and `banker`

Comment: Thanks both for your great help. Guess a better why to phrase my question. My original codes actually worked on a smaller set of data whilst it was unable to run on this larger piece of information. The larger data has around 745 rows. Based on my search on internet today i think it has to do with the ActiveSheet pasting as i said. I am attaching the whole set of code for you guys to see if what can be reduced down.

Comment: What do you say about an attachment? And usually 745 rows cannot be considere something huge for VBA... But, let us see your whole code. What do you intend using those two selections? Selecting the filtered range?

Comment: Do you really need help?

Answer (score 0):

1. You should copy your code as it is and no writing it. In this way you will avoid spelling mistakes (`Range ("$A$!:$Y$1000")` instead of `"A1:...`, `X1ToRight` instead of `XlToRight`, "_banker" instead of "banker"). Putting `Option Explicit` on top of your module, as recommended above will help.
2. A way to filter and copy the filter range, not involving the clipboard should be the next code. Please, test it and send some feedback:

```
Sub testFilterCopyRange()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, shNew As Worksheet, lastR As Long
  Dim banker As String, rng As Range, rngF As Range, arr, i As Long
  Dim maxIt As Long 'number of iterations
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row
  maxIt = 1                 'set here the maximum number of necessary iterations
  sh.AutoFilterMode = False 'eliminate the previous filter
  
  Set rng = sh.Range("A1:H" & lastR) 'set the range to be processed
  For i = 1 To maxIt
     banker = "7" '"your dinamic criteria"
     rng.AutoFilter field:=7, Criteria1:=banker      'filter the range according to above defined criteria
     Set rngF = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) 'set a range to keep the filtered cells in the range
    
     arr = arrayFromDiscRange(rngF, False) 'header inclusive
     Set shNew = Sheets.Add(After:=sh): shNew.Name = banker 'add a new sheet and name it
     shNew.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arr), UBound(arr, 2)).value = arr 'drop the array content at once
 Next i
End Sub

'function able to transform a filtered (discontinue) range in an array:
Private Function arrayFromDiscRange(rngF As Range, Optional NoHeader As Boolean = False) As Variant
    Dim arr, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, A As Range, R As Range, iRows As Long
    'count range rows
    For Each A In rngF.Areas
        iRows = iRows + A.rows.count
    Next A
    'Redim the array to keep the range
    ReDim arr(1 To iRows - IIf(NoHeader, 1, 0), 1 To rngF.Columns.count): k = 1
    
    For Each A In rngF.Areas 'iterate between the range areas:
        For Each R In A.rows  'iterate between the area rows:
            If NoHeader And k = 1 Then GoTo Later 'skip the first row, if no header wanted
                    For j = 1 To R.Columns.count 'iterate between the area row columns:
                        arr(k, j) = R.cells(1, j).value 'place each row cells value in the array row
                    Next j
                    k = k + 1   'intrement the array row to receive values
Later:
           Next
    Next A
    arrayFromDiscRange = arr 'returning the created array
End Function
```

If something unclear, even if I tried commenting all the code line which could be problematic in understanding, please do not hesitate to ask for clarifications.

Comment: Thanks so much FaneDuru - I tried to input the codes as the comments but it was too long. I have started another thread which gives a more comprehensive background to this case. Theoretically the codes should work on its own but a smaller set of data as I have done so but not sure how i could simplify it down:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68428082/reducing-activesheet-paste-size-large-data-showing-insufficient-memory. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: @12hcks Posted the updated code to replace yours. I adapted the above code in order to serve your need, as I could understand it from your question. I asked a clarification question, but no answer...  It should be very fast, using arrays and working only in memory. Please, test it and send some feedback.

Comment: I would like to state that my code does not really 'simplify' your code. It makes it faster and less memory consuming, as I understand from this question. Didn't you find some time to test it? I do not need such a code. I tried designing it only for you... If you want it (a little) faster, you should add optimization lines (`Application.ScreenUpdating = False`, `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`, `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`) at the code iteration beginning and make them `True/xlCalculationAutomatic` at the end. This only for the period when the new workbook is created...

Comment: Hi FaneDuru, tried your suggestion it says subscript out of range. arr(k, j) = R.Cells(1, j).Value 'place each row cells value in the array row. May i know what does that mean?

Comment: @12hcks Are you filtering on the correct column? This means that no filtered range to be processed exists... If such cases, when filtering result is nothing may exist, I can adapt the code to skip that `banker`... Is this your problem?

Comment: @12hcks I looked to your comment on the other answer and I could see that, in fact, you need filtering on column 6. Is that true? I will adapt the code to filter on that column... Adapted. Please, test it now and send some feedback. It should be very fast.

Comment: No worries, FaneDuru, I seem to be able to use the other codes to test for now. Again grateful for your help!

Comment: @12hcks I would like to clarify the next (important) issue: It is your right to choose whatever solution you like and understand better. But it is DISRESPECT **to not even test a code done for you, when you tagged me to help**. Especially in this context, when the code did not work only because of your wrong question. It perfectly answered your question **as it was*. If you are not able to understand the code quality, it is not your fault and I am not upset because of that.