# Reducing ActiveSheet Paste size. Large data showing insufficient memory

Tags: excel, vba

Would like seek help on simplifying down some codes. it worked on some smaller set of data but unable to work on this larger set of around 750rows of data. The aim is to simplify down the data set by the criteria of Banker, and saved each filtered results based on Banker on a new tab, and then save as a separate workbook.

```
Sub seperate_by_banker()

Dim i, n As Integer
Dim banker As String

i = 2
n = Sheets("Banker").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

Do Until i = n

banker = Sheets("Banker").Range("A" & i)

Sheets("ASIA CHINA (PC)").Select


ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$Y$1000").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:= _
    banker
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select

Selection.Copy
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Paste

ActiveSheet.Name = banker

i = i + 1

Loop

Call SplitWorkbook

End Sub

Sub SplitWorkbook()

'Updateby20200806
Dim FileExtStr As String
Dim FileFormatNum As Long
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim xWb As Workbook
Dim xNWb As Workbook
Dim FolderName As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set xWb = Application.ThisWorkbook

DateString = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss")
FolderName = xWb.Path & "\" & xWb.Name & " " &             DateString

If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
    FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
Else
    Select Case xWb.FileFormat
        Case 51:
        FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
        Case 52:
        If     Application.ActiveWorkbook.HasVBProject Then
            FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
        Else
            FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
        End If
    Case 56:
        FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
    Case Else:
        FileExtStr = ".xlsb": FileFormatNum = 50
    End Select
End If

MkDir FolderName

For Each xWs In xWb.Worksheets
On Error GoTo NErro
    If xWs.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
    xWs.Select
    xWs.Copy
    xFile = FolderName & "\" & xWs.Name & FileExtStr
    Set xNWb =     Application.Workbooks.Item(Application.Workbooks.Count)
    xNWb.SaveAs xFile, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
    xNWb.Close False, xFile
    End If
NErro:
    xWb.Activate
Next

    MsgBox "You can find the files in " & FolderName
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you want doing... Why saving "in a new tab (probable worksheet)" and "then save as a separate workbook"? Why not placing the processing result directly in such a (new) separate workbook? Then, if the workbook is of .xlsm type, do you really need the newly created workbook to be also .xlsm, even if it does not contain any code?

Comment: Hi FaneDuru, really appreciate your time in helping me on this. To clarify, I can process directly the results on a new workbook, just that I didnt know how to do it.

Comment: OK.  Then, try the code I posted. It means my previous answer to your similar question, able to completely avoid clipboard, adapted to the new situation.

Answer (score 1):

Please, try the next code. It uses array and copy the filtered range after transforming it in an array, so it should be very fast. No need of the second sub, no need of selections, which only consume Excel resources:

```
Sub seperate_by_banker()
  Dim shB As Worksheet, shAC As Worksheet, wbNew As Workbook, lastR As Long, lastRAC As Long
  Dim banker As String, rng As Range, rngF As Range, arrB, arr, i As Long, FolderName As String
  
  Set shB = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Banker")
  lastR = shB.Range("A" & shB.rows.count).End(xlUp).row     'last row
  arrB = shB.Range("A2:A" & lastR).Value2
  
  Set shAC = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ASIA CHINA (PC)")
  lastRAC = shAC.Range("A" & shAC.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row
  
  FolderName = ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name & " " & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss")
  If Dir(FolderName, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir FolderName 'create the folder if it does not exist
  
 For i = 1 To UBound(arrB)
    banker = arrB(i, 1)
    shAC.AutoFilterMode = False            'eliminate the previous filter, if any
    Set rng = shAC.Range("A1:Y" & lastRAC) 'set the range to be processed
    rng.AutoFilter field:=6, Criteria1:=banker
    Set rngF = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) 'set a range to keep the filtered cells in the range
    
    arr = arrayFromDiscRange(rngF, False) 'header inclusive
    
    'create the necessary new workbook:
    Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add
    With wbNew.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arr), UBound(arr, 2))
        .value = arr
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
    wbNew.saveas FolderName & "\" & banker & ".xlsx"
    wbNew.Close False
  Next i
End Sub
```

And the necessary function. It transforms the filtered (discontinuous) range in an array and paste it as fast as possible:

```
Private Function arrayFromDiscRange(rngF As Range, Optional NoHeader As Boolean = False) As Variant
    Dim arr, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, A As Range, R As Range, iRows As Long
    'count range rows
    For Each A In rngF.Areas
        iRows = iRows + A.rows.count
    Next A
    'Redim the array to keep the range
    ReDim arr(1 To iRows - IIf(NoHeader, 1, 0), 1 To rngF.Columns.count): k = 1
    
    For Each A In rngF.Areas 'iterate between the range areas:
        For Each R In A.rows 'iterate between the area rows:
            If NoHeader And k = 1 Then GoTo Later 'skip the first row, if no header wanted
                    For j = 1 To R.Columns.count  'iterate between the area row columns:
                        arr(k, j) = R.cells(1, j).value 'place each row cells value in the array row
                    Next j
                    k = k + 1   'increment the array row to receive values
Later:
           Next
    Next A
    arrayFromDiscRange = arr 'returning the created array
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create the new workbooks directly from the filtered sheet.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub separate_by_banker()

    Dim wb As Workbook, wbNew As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsData As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, arBanker As Variant
    Dim n As Long, iLastRow As Long
    Dim foldername As String, sName As String

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Banker")
    iLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    arBanker = ws.Range("A2:A" & iLastRow).Value2

    Set wsData = wb.Sheets("ASIA CHINA (PC)")
    iLastRow = wsData.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = wsData.Range("A1:Y" & iLastRow)
    
    ' make folder for workbooks
    foldername = wb.Path & "\" & wb.Name & " " & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss")
    MkDir foldername

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For n = 1 To UBound(arBanker)
        sName = arBanker(n, 1)
        Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet) ' 1 sheet
        wbNew.Sheets(1).Name = sName
        rng.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=sName
        rng.Copy
        wbNew.Sheets(1).Paste
        wbNew.Sheets(1).Columns("A:Y").AutoFit
        wbNew.SaveAs foldername & "\" & sName & ".xlsx"
        wbNew.Close False
    Next

    wsData.AutoFilterMode = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox n-1 & " files created in " & foldername, vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it saved beautifully. However, the filtered data doesnt show. Do you know why?The Banker Column is Column F if that helps. Many thanks!

Comment: What i mean is that the filtered sheet is empty once its sepearated out.

Comment: @12hcks Your code says `AutoFilter Field:=7`, if the column is F then try `AutoFilter Field:=6`

Comment: One more question, is there a way to also auto format the filtered worksheets? Can we auto format the width of the cells as some of them are too long and cant be read once clicked into it . Thanks.

Comment: @12hcks Add `wbNew.Sheets(1).Columns.AutoFit` before `wbNew.SaveAs`